# Convert date column from object data type to date-time data type

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime-format

I have a date column data type as object and I want to convert it to datetime data type. when I am trying to parse date while loading or trying doing this after loading using --pandas.to_datetime-- its taking too long to convert it since rows are in 100s of millions. Could someone help changing date from object to date type more efficiently and faster

Comment: Can you add some sample data to question? What is format of datetimes?

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas, **the only option to convert object to date-time is pd.to_datetime as it can't be done while reading the dataframe**.

I guess you're using the defaults:

```
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'])
```

**It'll be much faster if you specify the format of date-time while using pandas.to_datetime conversion**.

```
timefmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" 
df['Date_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_Time'], format = timefmt, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Actually aware of this(pd.to_datetime) as mentioned in the question also. I was looking for something faster.

Comment: Did you use the `timefmt` option and check if it's faster?